# Stop saving process when metabox is invalid

Tags: metabox, save-post, validation, errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent post from being published if custom fields not filled](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42013/prevent-post-from-being-published-if-custom-fields-not-filled)
>   [Check before publishing, if already exist post with current custom field value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46398/check-before-publishing-if-already-exist-post-with-current-custom-field-value)

I am trying to add some metaboxes to post edit page. They contain essential data for my template so I have to make sure they are filled and valid.

Validating them is not a problem. Before saving data I check them. But what to do when they are incorrect? I would like to stop saving process and print some nice error message but I have not found any reasonable way to do that. The post shall not be saved without these forms validly filled.

Thanks for help.

Comment: See also: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42178/9364. The above link refers to checking if meta data already exists in another post, and this if the mete data is 'invalid' - but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the links, they are really helpful. Trying to solve it.