# Prevent post from being published if no category selected

Tags: posts, publish

I do not want a user to be able to publish a post if no category is selected. I don't mind throwing a JS alert or handling this on the server side as well.

Anyway, how can I ensure this?

Note: "uncategorized" should not be chosen as well.

Comment: Maybe you can get inspiration [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42013/prevent-post-from-being-published-if-custom-fields-not-filled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with jQuery:

```
/* Checks if cat is selected when publish button is clicked */
jQuery( '#submitdiv' ).on( 'click', '#publish', function( e ) {
    var $checked = jQuery( '#category-all li input:checked' );

    //Checks if cat is selected
    if( $checked.length <= 0 ) {
        alert( "Please Select atleast one category" );
        return false;
    } else { 
        return true;
    }
} );
```

The above code will show an alert box if no category is selected. You can use dialog box instead if you'd like.

Comment: Though, I run a jQuery("form[name=post]").submit(handler);

Comment: not anymore `#publish` with wp5 and Guttenberg :/

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. I include this .js file on all Admin Pages, but since some of my custom post types don't include categories, I handle that situation by checking and returning true at the beginning of the function. I'm not an expert at JQuery, so I wrote most of this in straight JavaScript. Note that it specifically checks for the unpublished category, as well as checking the number of categories selected.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Check for exactly one category before publishing or updating
    $('#publish').click(checkForCategory);
});

function checkForCategory()
{
    var categoryBlock = document.getElementById('categorychecklist');
    if categoryBlock == null {
        return true;
    }
    var catList = categoryBlock.getElementsByClassName('selectit');

    var error = false;
    var idx;
    var selectedCnt = 0;
    var uncategorized = false;

    // Iterate through all of the categories to count the checked ones
    for (idx = 0; idx < catList.length; idx++) {
        inputElements = catList[idx].getElementsByTagName('input');
        if ((inputElements.length > 0) && (inputElements[0].checked)) {
            selectedCnt++;
            if (catList[idx].innerHTML.indexOf('Uncategorized') > 0) {
                uncategorized = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (uncategorized) {
        alert("You must unselect the Uncategorized category before publishing.");
        error = true;
    }
    else if (selectedCnt == 0) {
        alert("You must select a category before publishing.");
        error = true;
    }
    else if (selectedCnt > 1) {
        alert("You may only select one category when publishing.");
        error = true;
    }

    return !error;
}
```