# How to abort saving data in save_extra_profile_fields function Wordpress?

Tags: php, functions, user-meta

I am saving some additional fields using default wordpress user page in admin panel.

The function `save_extra_profile_fields()` used to save additional fields along with original user's fields.

(In short: i am modifying the user editing page in wordpress adminpanel)

In this function now i've some custom conditions/checks.

Some example code here :

```
//function to embed form fields
    function hf_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {
    <tr>

                        <th><label for="_user_status">User Status</label></th> 
                        <td class="user-status">

                        <?php $userstatus= esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'userstatus', $user->ID ) ); ?> 
                        <input type="radio" name="_user_status" value="active" <?php if ($userstatus == 'active') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> id="active"> <label for="active">ACTIVE</label> 



                        <input type="radio" name="_user_status" value="inactive" <?php if ($userstatus == 'inactive') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> id="inactive"> <label for="inactive">DEACTIVATE</label> 


                        </td>

                        </tr>
    }
    //function to get and save the data
        function hf_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
        if( empty($_POST['_user_status']) || $_POST['_user_status']=='inactive'){ 
                    return false;
                     //HERE THE ALERT SHOULD BE PROMPT AND SAVING DATA SHOULD BE ABORT
                    }
        }


        add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'hf_save_extra_profile_fields' ); 
        add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'hf_save_extra_profile_fields' );
```

**Question:** I want to abort all the functionality and show an alert box when it comes in to the specific condition.

**Note:** I don't want to use wp_die() method, because it takes user to next empty page and upon coming back the data gets clear into the fields. 
Into code above i just copied one field as an example. There are several fields.

Comment: Have you considered using Javascript to check the inputs and prevent the submission if they are not as required? See this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42013/prevent-post-from-being-published-if-custom-fields-not-filled#192686